# UnitsNet - Whats the best way to do runtime unit conversion

Tags: c#, .net, units-of-measurement

We are writing a data conversion application.

We have 10s of 1000s of equations that need to be extracted into a template aka ‘model’.

The model will take the most common unit of measure for a given set of equations.

Then each equation's value must be adjusted to ensure that its value corresponds to the unit of measure on the model.

So, I am looking to use UnitsNet to convert values of variables, given a source variable and its unit, to a target unit.

The issue I have is that we don’t know at compile time either what the source unit is, nor the target unit.

All we have is the source and target unit string abbreviations in the equation which comes in at runtime (and some of these will be custom units).

Simple example:

Target Unit: mA (Miliamperes)
Source Equation: Is=8A (Amperes)

We need to be able to recognize the unit of measure from the abbreviation, compare it to a target unit and then adjust the value accordingly :

e.g. in the above case we would multiply 8 Amperes by 1000 to equal 8000 Miliamperes.

I cannot see a succinct way to do this with UnitsNet.

Something crude like this is all I have so far (this is a unit test written in xUnit):

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("A", "mA", "8")]
public void DoConversion(string sourceUnit, string targetUnit, string variableValue)
{
    double result = 0;
    ElectricCurrent sourceCurrent;
    if (ElectricCurrent.TryParse($"{variableValue}{sourceUnit}", out sourceCurrent))
    {
        ElectricCurrent targetCurrent;
        if (ElectricCurrent.TryParse($"1{targetUnit}", out targetCurrent))
        {
            var electricCurrentUnit = GetElectricCurrentUnitFromAbbreviation(targetUnit);
            if (electricCurrentUnit == ElectricCurrentUnit.Ampere)
            {
                result = sourceCurrent.Amperes;
            }
            if (electricCurrentUnit == ElectricCurrentUnit.Milliampere)
            {
                result = sourceCurrent.Milliamperes;
            }
        }
    }
    result.Should().Be(8000);

    // TODO: Add every other combination of all possible Units and their Scales- OMG!!!

}

private ElectricCurrentUnit GetElectricCurrentUnitFromAbbreviation(string abbreviation)
{
    // Is there a better way to determine WHICH ElectricCurrentUnit the target is?
    if (abbreviation == "A")
        return ElectricCurrentUnit.Ampere;
    if (abbreviation == "mA")
        return ElectricCurrentUnit.Milliampere;

    return ElectricCurrentUnit.Undefined;
}
```

But the list of possible units we have to cater for is large, so I don’t want to have to write it this way.

It seems like there’s got to be a better way.

Would really appreciation your expert insight into this.

Comment: @anjdreas Any input on this one?

Comment: There are only a few base units to begin with, and hundreds of derived units when considering all the combinations and powers. It seems you need a different units library that can handle derived units from operator overloading (I have written one myself). It is not easy, but looking over [UnitsNet](https://github.com/anjdreas/UnitsNet) it doesn't seem like a good fit for your project.

Comment: Its an electrical engineering project and from what I can see in UnitsNet, the generated code in the UnitClasses namespace covers most things we need. So for the sake of the above, lets assume we dont need any units other than the ones included in UnitsNet - why then would you say UnitsNet is not a good fit?

Comment: [QuantityTypes](https://github.com/objorke/QuantityTypes) supports string parsing of prefixed units. Wortwhile to consider?

Comment: I was under the impression you had all sorts of combinations of units like `V^2/Ω` or `(mA)^(-1)` which won't have a static type in UnitsNet. I think you need a more general approach with a _single_ unit class, which contains the factors and exponents of each base unit (like in dimensional analysis), and such units can be derived from overloaded operators. For example for `1/Ω` you would type  `Unit InvOhm = Unit.Ampere/Unit.Volt`.

Answer (score 2):

This was answered on github: https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet/issues/220

## Proposed solution

This gives you some tools to more easily work with dynamic conversions, using string representations of quantities and units.

- New class [UnitConverter](https://github.com/anjdreas/UnitsNet/blob/master/UnitsNet/UnitConverter.cs)
- New property `Units` on quantities, ex: `LengthUnit[] Units { get; }` on `Length`
- Renamed (obsoleted) `UnitClass` enum to `QuantityType` for new naming convention

This allows the following scenario:

```
// Get quantities for populating quantity UI selector
QuantityType[] quantityTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(QuantityType)).Cast<QuantityType>().ToArray();

// If Length is selected, get length units for populating from/to UI selectors
LengthUnit[] lengthUnits = Length.Units;

// Perform conversion by using .ToString() on selected units
double centimeters = UnitConverter.ConvertByName(5, "Length", "Meter", "Centimeter");
double centimeters2 = UnitConverter.ConvertByAbbreviation(5, "Length", "m", "cm");
```